# WebLogic 12 SSLKeyException: Hostname verification failed after restart

Tags: ssl-certificate, weblogic12c

I have a WAR file deployed on WebLogic 12.1.2.0.0. Application calls a web service via HTTPS. Certificate is imported in DemoTrust.jks. All SSL related settings should be correct. And actually it works but after the server is restarted it does not work for about 15-20 minutes, after that it starts working again. During this period the following errors are printed in console:

```
<Warning> <Security> <BEA-090504> <Certificate chain received from xxx.xxxxxxxx.xxx.com - 
167.107.80.230 failed hostname verification check. Certificate contained xxx.xxxxxxxx.xxx.com 
but check expected xxx.xxxxxxxx.xxx.com>
```

After the warning I get:

```
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.net.ssl.SSLKeyException: Hostname verification failed: 
HostnameVerifier=weblogic.security.utils.SSLWLSHostnameVerifier,hostname=xxx.xxxxxxxx.xxx.com.
```

In the warning above contained and expected domains are identical.

Thank you for your help!

-E

Comment: Are you sure what is contained EXACTLY matches what was expected? Have you tried turning off hostname verification? In the admin console `Servers -> server name -> Configuration SSL tab -> Advanced -> Change Hostname Verification dropdown to None`

Comment: Hi, yes I'm sure. And yes, I've tried changing this dropdown to None. Still the same behavior.

Answer (score 28):

If this is an issue with wildcards in the certificate name (e.g. weblogic default verifier doesn't think the certificate for *.salesforce.com covers cs86.salesforce.com), WebLogic actually provides a custom verifier to use:  `weblogic.security.utils.SSLWLSWildcardHostnameVerifier`. This value should be entered in the SSL configuration for the server in `Console -> Servers -> {Server Name} -> SSL -> Advanced -> Custom Hostname Verifier`

Comment: This sounds like the preferable solution. Unfortunately I still get the error when setting the Verifier to custom using the weblogic.security.utils.SSLWLSWildcardHostnameVerifier. Weblogic seems to still use the default verifier weblogic.security.utils.SSLWLSHostnameVerifier. I restarted the server and I am using WLS 12.1.3

Comment: Associated documentation can be found at https://blogs.oracle.com/sravansarraju/entry/wildcard_ssl_certificate_support_in But did not work for me.

Comment: was the error message complaining on  weblogic.security.utils.SSLWLSWildcardHostnameVerifier or weblogic.security.utils.SSLWLSHostnameVerifier? If the later, did you apply the changes in weblogic console after modification?

Comment: This should be the solution in order to remains the verification active (instead of set the verifier to None, decreasing the security).

Comment: Excelente me funciono perfecto.

Answer (score 14):

admin console Servers -> server name -> Configuration SSL tab -> Advanced -> Change Hostname Verification dropdown to None

This worked for me.

Comment: This solution reduce the security level by not verifying the hostname.

Comment: But in developing or testing case it good

Answer (score 8):

`set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -DUseSunHttpHandler=true` helped me. Try to add this line to WebLogic `setDomainEnv.(cmd|sh)` file. The purpose of this parameter is to tell WebLogic to use Sun's HttpHandler and do not use WebLogic one.

Answer (score 1):

The change I made on Console didn't help me(Console -> Servers -> {Server Name} -> SSL -> Advanced -> Custom Hostname Verifier or None)
After that edited JAVA_OPTIONS property on setDomainEnv file.
No verification, ​I know it's not a nice solution  but it saved my day.
Added the following line

```
   -Dweblogic.security.SSL.ignoreHostnameVerification=true
```