# com.nimbusds.jose.RemoteKeySourceException: Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set: Hostname verification failed

Tags: java, jwt, nimbus, jwk

I am using Nimbus-JOSE-JWT library library (version 4.39).  Using this library, I am trying to do local JWT token validation which pulls down JWK set from the OAuth authorization server.

My code works perfectly fine when I run it within a JSE application, however, when I run the exact same code (as part of a JEE application) within WebLogic 12.1.3, it fails to run with the following exception:

```
com.nimbusds.jose.RemoteKeySourceException: Couldn't retrieve remote JWK set: Hostname verification failed: HostnameVerifier=weblogic.security.utils.SSLWLSHostnameVerifier, hostname=corpZ.oktapreview.com.
    at com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.RemoteJWKSet.updateJWKSetFromURL(RemoteJWKSet.java:141)
    at com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.RemoteJWKSet.get(RemoteJWKSet.java:219)
    at com.nimbusds.jose.proc.JWSVerificationKeySelector.selectJWSKeys(JWSVerificationKeySelector.java:129)
    at com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.process(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:323)
    at com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.process(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:284)
    at com.nimbusds.jwt.proc.DefaultJWTProcessor.process(DefaultJWTProcessor.java:275)
    at org.corpZ.sec.okta.OktaClient.getAccessTokenInfoLocally(Unknown Source)
    at org.corpZ.sec.okta.OktaClient.validateAccessTokenLocally(Unknown Source)
    at org.corpZ.sec.okta.TokenValidator.isTokenValid(Unknown Source)
    at org.corpZ.eis.ws.interceptor.WSInterceptor.handleRequest(WSInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.DelegatingSmartEndpointInterceptor.handleRequest(DelegatingSmartEndpointInterceptor.java:78)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:224)
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:173)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:88)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServ
```

Below is the Maven dependency that I have in my code:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.nimbusds</groupId>
  <artifactId>nimbus-jose-jwt</artifactId>
  <version>4.39</version>
</dependency>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Chrck this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27550586/weblogic-12-sslkeyexception-hostname-verification-failed-after-restart

Comment: Download source code Nimbus-JOSE-JWT and change the time out parameter in it.Make your own custom jar and use it.It will work .As of now , this timeout time is not configurable.

Comment: @V..S Please never do this. Custom copied Jars are a crime ;) By doing this you just subscribed your company to maintain a 3rd party library...

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never, this is due to WebLogic server configuration. You have to enter into SSL properties tab, and change the "Hostname Verification" to "none".